# Why identityserver3 did not return refresh token?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0

My client use implicit flow Of OAuth2. After logged in successful, the identityserver3 return access token,expires,scopes and so on. But it did not return refresh token.
 I have set the offline_access scope in request url, AllowedScopes of client and identityServerServiceFactory, it doesn't work. However if I change to the authorizaion code flow, the identityserver3 will return refresh token.

My code is as below:

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
     var authorizationUrl = 'http://localhost:44300/core/connect/authorize';
     var client_id = 'MyMobileApp';
     var redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:44300/JsImplicitFlowDemo.html';
     var response_type = "token";
     var scope = "offline_access";
     var state = Date.now() + "" + Math.random();
     localStorage["state"] = state;

     var url = authorizationUrl + "?" +
          "client_id=" + encodeURI(client_id) + "&" +
          "redirect_uri=" + encodeURI(redirect_uri) + "&" +
          "response_type=" + encodeURI(response_type) + "&" +
          "scope=" + encodeURI(scope) + "&" +
          "state=" + encodeURI(state);

           window.location = url;
});
```

Could you help me please, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have read the implicit flow spec of OAuth2 just now. The implicit grant type is used to obtain access tokens (it does not support the issuance of refresh tokens)